# sort and uniq a text file in perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I am working on a text file. It has multiple entries of lines and I am trying to sort and uniq the file. I am trying to write the output to the same file but it seems difficult. So I am writing to a different file. I have been able to sort but not get the unique.
Some lines in my text file

```
AB.CD.EF
BA.CD.EF
DC.AB.EF
CD.AB.EF
AB.CD.EF
DC.AB.EF
EF.CD.AB
BA.CD.EF
EF.DC.AB etc....
```

The code I am using to sort is

```
open(FH,'<mytext.txt');
open(OFH,'>myouttext.txt');
print OFH sort <FH>;
close(OFH);
close(FH);
```

I need to incorporate the unique part within this code or someother way, but still both the sort and unique should be done within the same code block. It would be great if it can be done and written to the same file. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use filehandle as the first argument of `open` is some kind of old-fashioned, a better practice is use 'indirect filehandle', see [Indirect Filehandles](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Indirect-Filehandles) for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open(FH, '<', 'mytext.txt') or die $!;
open(OFH,'>', 'myouttext.txt') or die $!;

my %seen;
print OFH sort grep !$seen{$_}++, <FH>;

close(OFH);
close(FH);
```

Saving changes to the same file using cmd line,

```
sort -u -o mytext.txt mytext.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I had used the above code but with some error in it. I didn't use , before <FH> and i used a variable i had used earlier in my script. So, it didnt work for me. This worked fine.

Comment: I didn't get an error, but it was printing some other junk values into the text file. I changed it now as you suggested and it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks mpapec. But i wanted this in a script. You code is working fine. Thank you.